# Ef Core Reconciler Not Accepting Null Child Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have been using this [Reconciler plugin](https://github.com/jtheisen/reconciler) in my dotnet core web application.

It is similar to GraphDiff but this plugin supports ef core.

I have these lines when I'm updating my model.

```
_context.Reconcile(applicationForm, r => r.WithMany(m => m.AccessArea).WithMany(m => m.TrainingRecord));
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The problem is, Reconcile() doesn't accept null parameter, so when I pass null child entity it hits error.

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source)
```

Any workaround for this?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to resolve this by making them an empty list instead of null.

Cheers!

```
if (applicationForm.AccessArea == null)
{
    applicationForm.AccessArea = new List<AccessAreaCheckBox>();
}
if (applicationForm.TrainingRecord == null)
{
    applicationForm.TrainingRecord = new List<FilePath>();
}
```